# How to check user inside bash script and run as another user

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I always want to run a script as user1, but the code flow always runs it as root. So, I want to check the current user inside the script. If it is root, I want to run the rest of the script as user1.

I want to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23256733/checking-if-root-inside-bash-script). But only difference is I need to run the script as a  particular user (say user1). So, when I find that the current user is not user1, I do not want to exit but want to run rest of the shell script as user1.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check this: https://superuser.com/questions/468161/howto-switch-chage-user-id-witin-a-bash-script-to-execute-commands-in-the-same/468163#468163

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea from a security perspective.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter who runs the script.  If it needs to run as `user1`, it should be on the caller to ensure that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @User123. But I was facing some issues with that solution as there are many functions and variables in the script. Not sure what the problem exactly is. But, this worked for me now:

```
 if [ $USER == <undesired user> ]; then
  echo Current user is $USER. Running the script as <desired user>
  su -c 'sh <script.sh>' <desired user>
 else
  echo Current user is $USER
  ...
  <rest of the script>
  ...
 fi
```